# ACF and Wordpress extract data from object

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have two Custom Post Types

- Buildings
- Apartments

They are connected thru Post Object. Apartment have field where i choose Building, and i can extract some data like ->

`<?php
    $ligging = get_field('project_for_apartment');
    ?>
    <?php the_field('location_facility', $ligging->ID) ?>`

With that code i extract location from Project page to apartment. That works without any error. But when i try to extract data from repeater field on project page i dont get any results. How can i extract data from fields in repeater (on another page)

Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 0):

The repeater field is usually used in a loop, as its name implies. Have you looked at their doco?

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Comment: I know how to use repeater if i target ACF to that template. But i dont know how to extract value of field inside repetear in another not targeted template via object.

Comment: Ok let me explain better because i am real stuck here. I have custom post type Projects (buildings), and i have custom post type Apartments. How can i assign some specific apartments to belong to some projects. For example i have Project 1, Project 2, and i have Apartment 1 and Apartment 2. How can i create relationship between those , i want to asign Apartment 2 to Project 1. Then i want to display on apartment-single.php some data from project 1 like location, features etc.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of a repeater field (when not used in a loop) is an array, so you could do something like this:

```
$repeater = get_field('field_name');
foreach($repeater as $field){
    echo $field['sub_field_name'];
}
```